# Token URI not found on Opensea

Tags: erc-721, nft, brownie, opensea, meta-data

I ran `brownie run scripts/rizer_incept/set_tokenuri.py --network rinkeby` and I got this error

```
TransactionError: Tx dropped without known replacement: 0x0a3c830623e6cd6d07783902f418cd1c3e169ebf1bcb08390f32ddf7aadae291
```

and when I ran it again I got this

```
Running 'scripts/rizer_incept/set_tokenuri.py::main'...
Working on rinkeby
The number of tokens you've deployed is: 1
Skipping 0, we already set that tokenURI!
```

The problem is that there is no image for the token on opensea:
https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x85994881438ed80948e2abacf9be29bf3d49f595/0

I correctly uploaded the json metadata and image to ipfs. See these content hashes

```
QmdxacdJ3VAXThKB2xbYCPBE9KWq8VfGHhdKhrFWMKGVij - metadata json file
QmNfavcLue8H9bsY5CC4v9rx4DSpwrVmEiC5ndjEsM8v1R - png image
```

this is my code in the file `set_tokenuri.py`, I got the code from https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/nft-mix with some minor modifications.

```
from brownie import RizerIncept, accounts, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_type, OPENSEA_FORMAT


rizer_metadata_dic = {
    "FIRST_R": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdxacdJ3VAXThKB2xbYCPBE9KWq8VfGHhdKhrFWMKGVij?filename=first-r.png",
}

def main():
    print("Working on " + network.show_active())
    rizer_incept = RizerIncept[len(RizerIncept) - 1]
    number_of_rizer_incepts = rizer_incept.tokenCounter()
    print(
        "The number of tokens you've deployed is: "
        + str(number_of_rizer_incepts)
    )
    for token_id in range(number_of_rizer_incepts):
        rizerType = get_type(rizer_incept.tokenIdToRizerType(token_id))
        if not rizer_incept.tokenURI(token_id).startswith("https://"):
            print("Setting tokenURI of {}".format(token_id))
            set_tokenURI(token_id, rizer_incept,
                         rizer_metadata_dic[rizerType])
        else:
            print("Skipping {}, we already set that tokenURI!".format(token_id))


def set_tokenURI(token_id, nft_contract, tokenURI):
    dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    nft_contract.setTokenURI(token_id, tokenURI, {"from": dev})
    print(
        "Awesome! You can view your NFT at {}".format(
            OPENSEA_FORMAT.format(nft_contract.address, token_id)
        )
    )
    print('Please give up to 20 minutes, and hit the "refresh metadata" button')
```

Also I checked on checkmynft.com and I got `Error: Could not fetch token URI.`
[image]

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: `checkmynft.com` would only work for contracts on the Ethereum mainet, it won't work for the contracts deployed on Ethereum test networks like rinkeby.

Comment: Oh gotcha, makes sense now. Thanks for the info.